# Unity sidebar not to launch a Chrome if already running

Tags: unity

How can I configure Unity's sidebar to have the following behaviour:

1) If I click on a program icon, and it's already running - switch to it.

2) If I click on a program icon, and it's not running - launch it.

More similar to Mac, or Windows 7's behaviour.

It currently does not work for Google Chrome.

Comment: Which program are you using which doesn't already behave this way? You may be able to fix it by editing the EXEC field in its .desktop launcher. Most programs already do behave as you stated.

Comment: @Dorkus1218, Google chrome opens a new window

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure unity do these things.

Answer (score 1):

Unity launcher does both the things you want. Just in case you want to have another instance of applications middle click does the job.